# Adding up for each occurence in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to add the quantity of an ingredient for each occurance of the ingredient. For example, if I have these:

```
Eggs    4
Bread   1
Tomato  1
Eggs    3
Grapefruit 2
Milk    1
Eggs    2
Banana  1
```

in two columns in excel, what formula can I use to count how many eggs I have? So I would have output like this:

```
Eggs    9
Bread   1
Tomato  1 ...
```

Obviously my list is extremely long so I otherwise I'd add it up myself. VLOOKUP only returns the quantity of the first occurence of "Eggs" and the rest are ignored.

You help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)? Like `=SUMIF(A:A, "Eggs", B:B)`

Comment: I knew I had to be overthinking it. Had to be something simple. Thanks

Comment: Or just use pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest/fastest way is to create a simple pivot table using Ingredient as rows and Qty as values (sum), please see the screenshot
[image: Pivot table]

If you are not familiar with the Pivot table, here is the detailed tutorial for beginners
[How to use Pivot Tables in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/11/19/excel-pivot-table-tutorial/)